# Too much whitespace breaks markdown side-by-side diff

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, markdown, diff

I came across this "bug" when reviewing [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23088609). The review basically removes a lot of useless whitespace from a codeblock (that was used to show a stacktrace). This is how it looks like on the "markdown side-by-side diff":

[image: Markdown side-by-side diff]

As can be seen, the removal of the whitespace characters is overflowing into the right side of the diff. The "rendered output diff" is correct:

[image: Rendered output diff]